# Scaling an image with a div, whose child sets the height

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

A div, by itself, is the height of it's contents.

I want a div to include two children: another div (or image that is left aligned) and an unordered list (ul). The inner div (or image) will match the height of the parent div, the parent div height will conform to the height of the list (which can contain any reasonable number of items).

I am unsure how to set the height of the parent div to match that of the list and have the inner div match the height of the outer div. Done properly through CSS.

Alternate solutions are happily accepted, this is just one way I am attempting to address my design goals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/WA9Tv/)

- Tested in IE7/IE8, and recent versions of: Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera.
- The height of the image is purely dependent on the height of the `ul`.
- To feed IE7 the required extra rule `height: 100%`, I'm using the [Star hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_hack). You could use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html), or the [Star plus hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_plus_hack) instead if you need 100% valid CSS.

**CSS:**

```
#iContainer {
    background: #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative
}
#iContainer div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    *height: 100% /* just for you, IE7 */
}
#iContainer img {
    height: 100%
}
#iContainer ul {
    float: right
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="iContainer">

    <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x700/f0f/fff" /></div>

    <ul>
        <li>list 1</li>
        <li>list 2</li>
        <li>list 3</li>
        <li>list 4</li>
        <li>list 5</li>
        <li>list 6</li>
        <li>list 7</li>
        <li>list 8</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

**The Big Pink Image:**

[image]

Comment: OP - choose this over mine much nicer

Comment: @Sarabjot: Let me know if you run into any problems with this, it's not something I've tried before. I'd be interested to hear of any caveats (when you come to use it on a real site).

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought it was something along these lines, elegant solution. It is being used in a mathematics site to represent linear systems. The left image is actually a open brace.

Answer (score 3):

Does this do what you are after?

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/CQG8s/

It uses a small (pure JS) script to measure the list height on page load then dynamically set the div's height via the `.style.height` method :)

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you! Unfortunately JS is not an option. If I pitch that to the boss, he'll just tell me to figure it out using tables. I am trying to restrict my answer to CSS and HTML, but I can see where that might not be possible.

Comment: The image containing div is non-repeating, just scaling to the height of the list.

Comment: Will you not get mad pixelation with that?

Comment: It is a large image that is being scaled down -- it's a single ASCII character with defined edges, so pixelation doesn't seem to be much of an issue. The problem is that it needs to match the height of the list.

Comment: @thirtydot Yayy condolences :D

Comment: @Sarabjot use @thirtydot solution below :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a div to match the height of its container, set its height to 100%.  If you want a div to use up as much space as available, set its height to auto (default).

So, it sounds like the layout you're looking for is

```
<style type="text/css">
 .scaledimage{height:100%;float:left}
 .list{float:left;}
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="scaledimage"></div>
  <div class="list"></div>
<div>
```