# dynamic and fixed size in CSS

Tags: html, css

I need in the same HTML row to have 2 divs: one will stay the same width while the other's size will be increased once the web page is being increased by the end user.

So I defined one div and inside 2 divs like this:

```
<div>
    <div style="float:left" width="20px">first div</div>
    <div style="float:left" width="100%">first div</div>
</div>
```

However it does not work!

How can I create 2 divs in the same line that one will be fixed size and the other one relative?

Comment: You have an extra colon after "float:left:"

Comment: @Odelya Is the row width fixed?

Comment: @Sime the row width is not fixed - 100% as well

Comment: @Odelya Should the two DIVs have the same height? Is it a fixed value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do I win?

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/sFtD8/)

[***Live Demo #2***](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/sFtD8/1/) (using classes and with support for more than one instance of this)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="divHolder">
    <div id="div1">1</div>
    <div id="div2">2</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#divHolder {
    overflow: auto
}
#div1 {
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    background: #ccc
}
#div2 {
    margin-left: 20px;
    background: #888
}
```

Comment: +1 for a simple solution. It didn't even occur to me that #div2 wouldn't also have to be float:left.

Comment: +1 for nice clean solution, man I gotta jump on CSS questions before you do or i'll never even hit 3K never mind the 10k you're steaming towards!

Comment: @Myles Gray: Thanks. I think I might have just [done it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224885/scaling-an-image-with-a-div-whose-child-sets-the-height/5225718#5225718) to you again, sorry :D

Comment: that is both impressive and annoying at the same time, well done sir :D +1 once it gets past midnight ;)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Shaz/GaZYt/2/

The left box will change size depending how much horizontal space is left. The right box will always have a minimum and maximum width of 200px.

Comment: The red box overflows the viewport.

Comment: @Šime: This should be fixed, try again.

Comment: I've simplified your code: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/GaZYt/3/ It seems that you don't need most of those CSS properties.

Comment: This is better (than my answer) if both `div`s should be the same height regardless of the content. It's not so good if IE7 support is required (no `display: table` without hacktastic magic).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting display:inline on the div elements.  The default display value for a div is block (which causes them to appear on seperate lines).  Here is an example on [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5yDz2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may need to use Javascript to handle this case.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var $left = $('#left');
  var $container = $('#container');
  $right.width($container - $left);
});
```