# Left align float:right div

Tags: html, css

I am following the accepted answer to [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224885/scaling-an-image-with-a-div-whose-child-sets-the-height).

In the above question, the layout consists of an image followed by an unordered list (see the JSFiddle in the question above).

In my site, I am trying to do the same thing, except:

- Instead of an unordered list I am using a div with some content (this is not a big issue)
- I want the div (currently contains some text) to be **left**-aligned, instead of the right-aligned behaviour in the example.

I have tried setting it to `float:left`, however the image then obscures the div.
I also tried to create another div with a `&nbsp;` and set its width to 100% and `float:right` as well so as to try and create a "buffer" which will push the div with content back over to the left, however the buffer also pushes the div too far left.

What do I need to do in order to have the same behaviour as in the JSFiddle example except having the unordered list left-aligned? I can probably handle the rest from there.

**Edit**
To be clear I want it to look like this:

```
|---------||-------------------|            Empty space                  |
|   Image || Unordered List    |   |--------------------------|      ... |End of page
|_________||___________________|                                         |
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle demonstrating what happens?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle to demo?

Comment: @DanGoodspeed Thats spooky!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/WA9Tv/ is the fiddle from the previous example. I want the text from the unordered list to be left aligned next to the image

Comment: Also, see the edit above for an illustration of what I would like it to look like

Comment: @ose does your 1st div with the image have a css display property set?

Comment: @J2D8T no it does not, the div containing the image has the same style as "#iContainer div" in the JSFiddle

Comment: The `#iContainer div` has an position property set to absolute and that is what is tricking your float left into thinking there is nothing there. That is why it is moving in behind the 1st div.

Comment: @J2D8T when I remove the position absolute, the image expands to its regular size. The idea is that this image is supposed to match the height of the unordered list in the JSFiddle

Comment: I saw that from the jsfiddle but then you will have to give your ul a `margin-left` to push it out from under the 1st div

Comment: I will add it as an answer.

Comment: @J2D8T Please do and I'll give it a shot

Comment: Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/WA9Tv/34/).

Comment: @mdesdev I tried your fiddle but the unordered list is still right-aligned

Comment: Sorry, maybe something like this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/WA9Tv/43/)?

Comment: @mdesdev See J2D8T's answer below. The problem is that the padding value is hard-coded so when the size of the unordered list changes (particularly if it has less elements) there becomes a large gap between the image and the list.

Comment: @Pete this still hasn't been solved. The image is not of fixed width. The idea is that the image expands to the height of the unordered list to its right, but that unordered list needs to be left-aligned (so the text is next to the image)

Comment: @ose because the size of your image is dynamic this isn't going to be possible with pure css unless you start using the calc function (which isn't fully supported). I would recommend you should go with a javascript solution to resize the image once the content has been loaded.  [This is the best](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/WA9Tv/52/) I could do but unfortunately the width won't increase when the height does

Comment: [A working answer with js](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/WA9Tv/53/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of floating the list to the right.
Instead add a padding-left to the list, with the width of the image (myImg is the id of the image, and myUl being the id of the list):

```
var imgWidth = $("#myImg").width();
$("#myUl").css("padding-left", imgWidth.toString() + "px");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/78zT3/1/

Answer (score 0):

You will have to give the `ul` a margin-left to push it out from under the first div. Because the first div has `position: absolute;` the other elements doesn't recognize the dimensions of that div and ignores it.

Here is revised code [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WA9Tv/31/)

The only changes is in the `#iContainer ul`.

Comment: I tried the solution, it is certainly progress, but I was hoping to avoid a hard-coded margin-left. If you see this fiddle, I have changed the elements in the unordered list and now there is a large gap between the image and the list. Is there a way to avoid this? http://jsfiddle.net/WA9Tv/33/

Answer (score 0):

[See here for the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WA9Tv/32/)

Crucially note that the 'image' has its position set to absolute, so when you left float the list it appears beneath it. You thus need to set its position to relative, whilst also floating it left.

Revised CSS:

```
#iContainer {
    background: #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative
}
#iContainer div {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    *height: 100% /* just for you, IE7 */
}
#iContainer img {
    height: 100%;
}
#iContainer ul {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that now the image expands to its full size. The image is supposed to be restricted to the same height as the unordered list.